# PHP Cron Read CSV from URL and Convert to Array

Tags: php, csv, cron

I am trying to develop email system that need to be send every month. So i need to build cron job file from php. Anyone know how to read file CSV or Excel file from url such as: 
http://yourdomain.com/cron.php?file=http://google.com/monthly.csv

I am stuck when try to read file from url.

This is my recent code:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www1.intranet.com/reportingtool.asp?settings=var&export=ok';
$tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir());
file_put_contents(
    $tmpfname,
    file_get_contents($url)
);
?>
```

Comment: go to manual and read up on fgetcsv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with remote files, you should always keep in mind that

- The connection between you and the remote can break, and you won't get the full file content;
- The file can be too big to read it on-the-fly.

In both cases, `file_get_contents()` is not a very good thing to use: you should consider [cURL functions](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for that. However, if the concerns above are negligible, you should be okay with the following (as the [example here](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) suggests):

```
$url = 'http://www1.intranet.com/reportingtool.asp?settings=var&export=ok';
$tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir());
file_put_contents(
    $tmpfname,
    file_get_contents($url)
);
if (($handle = fopen($tmpfname, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // Do something with $data, which comes in
        // as an array of values from the current CSV line.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone would need one more example, so leaving it here:
`$dataSource` can be any file on drive or just online link to parse csv.

```
private array $data = [];
    private string $dataSource = "https://any.csv";
    

    if (($open = fopen($dataSource, 'rb')) !== false)
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($open, 1000, ";")) !== false)
        {
            $data[] = $data;
        }
        fclose($open);
    }
```